# can you make your terminal so that it times all the commands except common ones?

Tags: bashrc

Is it possible to configure your shell(bash) so that it times all the commands except the common ones(like ls or cd)?

so when I type some command like

```
command arg1 arg2
```

I would want my terminal to convert it into behind the scene

```
time command arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Maybe this will be of use to you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12059/forcing-an-added-alias-to-every-command

Comment: Define common. I use `ls`,`cd`,`rm`,`mv`,`pwd`,`echo`,`mkdir`,`rmdir`,`cp`,`more`,`less`,`ps`,`diff` etc etc every day. It would probably be better to configure your shell to `time` the few specific commands you actually want to time or _all_ commands as described in the link that @Rain posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe an alias is the answer.
create as many aliases as you want.

alias cp='time cp'

Comment: I haven't done this outside of scripting, so I don't know if `alias` is smart enough, but but it might be a good idea to use `time \cp` instead of `time cp` so it forces it to use the system `cp` command instead of the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute the following command to add the time stamp to the history:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

Then if you logout and log back in whenever you invoke the history command you will see a time stamp for the commands you executed. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like it appends a time stamp to the .bash_history file in a user's local home profile. It would also appears it doesn't have a way of distinguishing common vs. uncommon executed commands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, here I am referring "time" as a unix command time for benchmarking